# Orbot: can't exclude exit country

Tags: orbot, android

I'm trying to set Orbot up not to exit in certain countries, eg, United States. However, if I set it to exclude `United States` or similar, Orbot refuses to connect to Tor.

I've tried to apply TLD's (`.us`), ISO 3166-formatted country codes, short- and longnames both with and without quotes, but still no luck.

If the idea is to only exclude single fingerprints, then it's going to take a while to exclude them all.

Any suggestions?

Orbot v15.4.1-RC-1-multi on Android 7.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use curly brackets like this:

```
{us},{gb}
```

The syntax corresponds to the one of [ExcludeNodes in torrc](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#ExcludeNodes).

Comment: I thought it would be `{uk}` but you're correct, countries codes are according to [ISO 3166-1 alpha-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2) so `{gb}` is the way to go.